# getting Unexpectect token on useState declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hey i am trying to declare a useState hook with interface type but i am getting Unexpected token this is mi code

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import DataGrid, {Scrolling,HeaderFilter,FilterRow,Pager,Selection} from 'devextreme-react/data-grid';
import 'devextreme/dist/css/dx.light.css';



var json = require('./json/tacticalplanning.json');

let columns = [{dataField:'materialDescription',caption:'Descripcion',width: 125},
{dataField:'reference',caption:'Referencia',width: 100}
];
let columns2 = [];
let data = [];
let data2 = [];

interface iData {
  [key:string]:any
}

const [dataState,setDataState] = useState<iData[]>([]); //here is the unexpected token problem
```

Comment: That seems perfectly valid.

Comment: Where is the error being reported?

Comment: It looks like you use TypeScript code inside the JavaScript project. Do you have TypeScript set up?